Choose the correct statements on set.
I am supposed to choose the right option (s)

If $A∪C=B∪C$ then $A=B$
If $A∩ C=B∩C$ then $A=B$
If $A∪C⊆B∪C$ and if $A∩C⊆B∩C$ then $A⊆B$
If $A∪C⊆B∪C$ and if $A∩C⊆B∩C$ then $A=B$

My attempt:

Option 1 can be discarded if I take set $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{3,4\}, C=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

So, option 1 is false.

Option 2 can be discarded if I take set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}, B=\{2,4,5\}, C=\{2,4\}$

So, option 2 is false.
Unable to decide on 3 and 4 options.
Kindly help. I really appreciate any help you can provide. Can we apply some set theory concepts for options 3 and 4?

The game is proof or counterexample.
If you are unable to give a counterexample, it is maybe the right time to search for a proof.
Vise versa, if you can not give a proof, maybe try to construct a counterexample.
So lets try to proof statement 3.
For this we have to proof that under the assumption that
$A\cup C \subseteq B\cup C$ and $A\cap C\subseteq B\cap C$ then $A\subseteq B$.
So we have to prove a subset inclusion.
These proofs are formulated as follows.
To show $A\subseteq B$ we have to start with an arbitrary $a\in A$.
If we are able to show that $a\in B$, we are done.
So let $a\in A$.
We know that $a\in A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$. So $a\in B\cup C$. By definition of the union we know that $a\in B$ or $a\in C$. So not quite what we have to show. (We have to pin down that $a\in B$.)
So lets observe the possibilities.
If $a\in B$ we are done.
So what If $a\in C$.
This means that $a\in A\cap C$.
Now by our second assumption we know that $a\in B\cap C$.
By definition of the intersection we have that $a\in B$ and $a\in C$ which means that $a\in B$. This is what we had to prove.
So this statement is true.
Now try to show 4. yourself.
The first have is in 3.
Note that there you have to show equality of sets.
This is done in two steps.
First show $A\subseteq B$ (this is statement 3).
Next try to show $B\subseteq A$ (this is what you have to try yourself now).
The proof (if existent) has to be formulated as shown above.
Start with $b\in B$. Try to conclude $b\in A$.

Cornman, you cannot prove that $B\subseteq A$ relatively to the statement $4$. A counterexample is $A={1}$, $B={1,2,3}$ and $C={1,2,4}$.

In my answer I do not claim that it can be proven. My goal was to make the TS try to prove it, and see if it works or not.

Cornman, you wrote “try to show $B\subseteq A$ ( this is what you have to try yourself now)”. You should not confuse the original poster by asking them something it is impossible. It would be fairer to suggest looking for a counterexample.
